# Why am I missing parameters in this data?

Tags: r, categorical-data

The following data are from Table 7.28 in " Introduction to Categorical Data Analysis" (2nd edition). I am trying to fit an independence model and I think I almost have it, but for some reason the factors TBC1 and religious1 are missing from the summary. How do I get them to show up? Am I using the wrong regression? This is done in R studio.

```
religious=c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 4), rep(4, 4), rep(5, 4), rep(6, 4), rep(7, 4), rep(8, 4), rep(9, 4))

TBC=c(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), 9))

count=c(49, 49, 19, 9, 31, 27, 11, 11, 46, 55, 25, 8, 34, 37, 19, 7, 21, 22, 14, 16, 26, 36, 16, 16, 8, 16, 15, 11, 32, 65, 57, 61, 4, 17, 16, 20)

relig.TBC=data.frame(religious, TBC, count)

relig.TBC$religious=factor(relig.TBC$religious, levels=sort(unique(relig.TBC$religious)))
relig.TBC$TBC=factor(relig.TBC$TBC, levels=sort(unique(relig.TBC$TBC)))

relig.TBC.glm=glm(count~religious+TBC, family=poisson, data=relig.TBC)

q=summary(relig.TBC.glm)
q
```

Comment: You are missing nothing, the levels `1` of both variables are the base levels of that model. Try the formula `count ~ 0 + religious + TBC` to remove the intercept and see level `religious1`. What are the values of the previous model's intercept and of this one's `religious1`?

Comment: `religious = rep(1:9, each=4)`